# DataFrame remove useless columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i use the following code to build and prepare my pandas dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('statistic.csv', 
parse_dates=True, index_col=['DATE'], low_memory=False)
data[['QUANTITY']] = data[['QUANTITY']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
data_extracted = data.groupby(['DATE','ARTICLENO']) 
['QUANTITY'].sum().unstack()
#replace string nan with numpy data type
data_extracted = data_extracted.fillna(value=np.nan)
#remove footer of csv file
data_extracted.index = pd.to_datetime(data_extracted.index.str[:-2], 
errors="coerce")
#resample to one week rythm
data_resampled = data_extracted.resample('W-MON', label='left', 
loffset=pd.DateOffset(days=1)).sum()
# reduce to one year
data_extracted = data_extracted.loc['2015-01-01' : '2015-12-31']
#fill possible NaNs with 1 (not 0, because of division by zero when doing 
pct_change
data_extracted = data_extracted.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).fillna(1)
data_pct_change = 
data_extracted.astype(float).pct_change(axis=0).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 
np.nan).fillna(0)
# actual dropping logic if column has no values at all
data_pct_change.drop([col for col, val in data_pct_change.sum().iteritems() 
if val == 0 ], axis=1, inplace=True)
normalized_modeling_data = preprocessing.normalize(data_pct_change, 
norm='l2', axis=0)
normalized_data_headers = pd.DataFrame(normalized_modeling_data, 
columns=data_pct_change.columns)
normalized_modeling_data = normalized_modeling_data.transpose()
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(normalized_modeling_data)
print(kmeans.labels_)
np.savetxt('log_2016.txt', kmeans.labels_, newline="\n")
for i, cluster_center in enumerate(kmeans.cluster_centers_):
        plp.plot(cluster_center, label='Center {0}'.format(i))
plp.legend(loc='best')
plp.show()
```

Unfurtunately there are a lot of 0's in my dataframe (the articles don't start at the same date, so so if A starts in 2015 and B starts in 2016, B will get 0 through the whole year 2015)
Here is the grouped dataframe:

```
ARTICLENO     205123430604  205321436644  405659844106  305336746308  
DATE                                                                     
2015-01-05            9.0            6.0          560.0         2736.0   
2015-01-19            2.0            1.0          560.0         3312.0   
2015-01-26            NaN            5.0          600.0         2196.0   
2015-02-02            NaN            NaN           40.0         3312.0   
2015-02-16            7.0            6.0          520.0         5004.0   
2015-02-23           12.0            4.0          480.0         4212.0   
2015-04-13           11.0            6.0          920.0         4230.0
```

And here the corresponding percentage change:

```
ARTICLENO     205123430604   205321436644  405659844106  305336746308  
DATE                                                                     
2015-01-05       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000   
2015-01-19      -0.777778      -0.833333       0.000000       0.210526   
2015-01-26      -0.500000       4.000000       0.071429      -0.336957   
2015-02-02       0.000000      -0.800000      -0.933333       0.508197   
2015-02-16       6.000000       5.000000      12.000000       0.510870   
2015-02-23       0.714286      -0.333333      -0.076923      -0.158273
```

The factor 12 at 405659844106 is 'correct'
Here is another example from my dataframe:

```
ARTICLENO     305123446353  205423146377  305669846421  905135949255  
DATE                                                                     
2015-01-05         2175.0          200.0            NaN            NaN   
2015-01-19         2550.0            NaN            NaN            NaN   
2015-01-26          925.0            NaN            NaN            NaN   
2015-02-02          675.0            NaN            NaN            NaN   
2015-02-16         1400.0          200.0          120.0            NaN   
2015-02-23         6125.0          320.0            NaN            NaN
```

And the corresponding percentage change:

```
ARTICLENO      305123446353  205423146377  305669846421    905135949255  
DATE                                                                  
2015-01-05       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000    0.000000   
2015-01-19       0.172414      -0.995000       0.000000   -0.058824   
2015-01-26      -0.637255       0.000000       0.000000    0.047794   
2015-02-02      -0.270270       0.000000       0.000000   -0.996491   
2015-02-16       1.074074     199.000000     119.000000  279.000000   
2015-02-23       3.375000       0.600000      -0.991667    0.310714
```

As you can see, there are changes of factor 200-300 which comefrome the change of the replaced NaN to a real value.

This data is used to do a kmeans-clustering and such 'nonsense'-data ruins my kmeans-centers.

Does anyone have an idea how to remove such columns?

Comment: Have you tried to fill your DataFrame using a forward, or backward fill? See the 'method' argument for DataFrame.fillna.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. Your example has too much information and is confusing. pd.DataFrame.drop() is one way to drop columns.

Can you provide some more info about the columns you are trying to drop? Do they all have large numbers, do they all have a certain type of label, etc?

Comment: I want to remove the columns that contain 'nonsense' values like the second example. Reading the dataframe with my grouby statement allows me to access the different quantities by the article number used as columns of the dataframe, but this way produces '0' entries for dates where the csv file did not contain an entry for the specific date-article number tuple. Interpolating would be one way, but i don't want to use this because it would falsify my clustering with data that did not exist in the csv. Can i check for the percentage of NaNs in a column?

Comment: Question is solved, i summed the NaNs per column and dropped them if the sum is above a maximum value

Answer (score 0):

I used the following statement to drop the nonsense columns:

```
max_nan_value_count = 5
data_extracted = data_extracted.drop(data_extracted.columns[data_extracted.apply(lambda 
col: col.isnull().sum() > max_nan_value_count)], axis=1)
```